# Powershell Replace not working with user input

Tags: powershell

The below code works perfect but If i try to get user input for $source:

```
$Source= Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the source directory (example c:\dir1)"
```

The Replace does not work.  It keeps it as `$source` instead of making it Dir2
Can anyone help me figure this out?  I have been messing with it for a couple hours now

```
$Source = "C:\Dir1" 
$Destination = "C:\Dir2" 
$LogfilePath = $Destination + "\Log.txt"
    
Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $NewDir = $_.DirectoryName.Replace($Source, $Destination) 
    #see if destination directory exists
    if (-not(Test-Path -Path $NewDir)) {
        New-Item -Path $NewDir -ItemType Directory | Out-Null   
    }
    Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $NewDir
    Write-Host '.' -NoNewline
    #added to validate time stamp in log file is working
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    "$([DateTime]::Now) copied - '$($_.name)' from '$($_.DirectoryName)' to '$NewDir' Size: $([System.Math]::Round(($($_.Length)/1KB),2))KB"  | Add-Content $LogfilePath
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are **two conceivable scenarios** (possibly in combination) in which `$_.DirectoryName.Replace($Source, $Destination)` ***wouldn't* work as intended**, and they're not related to `Read-Host` per se:

- **`$Source` has a *trailing* `\`** (e.g., `C:\Dir1\` instead of `C:\Dir1`)

  - In this case, the `.Replace()` call malfunctions at least for files immediately located in the target path, because `.DirectoryName` values do *not* have a trailing `\` (except for files in a *root* path such as `C:\`).
- Perhaps more likely: **`$Source` *differs in case*** from the actual target path; e.g., `c:\dir1` vs. `C:\Dir1`

  - In this case, the **`.Replace()`** call fails, because this method **is case-*sensitive***, *invariably* in Windows PowerShell, *by default* in PowerShell (Core) 7+.

You could fix those problems by **using a *substring* approach instead of trying to *replace* the start of the path**, which bypasses the case-sensitivity problem:

```bash
# Remove the input path from the start and prepend the destination path.
Join-Path $Destination $_.DirectoryName.Substring($Source.Length)
```

Note that, due to how [`Join-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path) works, the path will be synthesized correctly *whether or not `$Source` has a trailing* `\`, so there is no need to trim one manually first. E.g.,
`Join-Path c:\dir2 sub`, `Join-Path c:\dir2 \sub`, and `Join-Path c:\dir2\ \sub`
all yield the same result: `c:\dir2\sub`.

---

**Alternative approach**: [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) has a **`-Name` switch** that reports matching files as *relative path strings*, namely relative to the input directory. This allows for a solution that uses PowerShell cmdlets only, without needing to resort to .NET method calls:

```bash
# Note the use of -Name
Get-ChildItem -Name -Path $Source -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    # Prepend the destination path to the parent path of the relative source path.
    $NewDir = Join-Path $Destination (Split-Path -Parent $_)
    # Ensure that the destination dir. exists - note the use of -Force
    $null = New-Item -Force -Path $NewDir -ItemType Directory
    Copy-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Destination $NewDir
    Write-Host '.' -NoNewline
    #added to validate time stamp in log file is working
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    "$([DateTime]::Now) copied - '$($_.name)' from '$($_.DirectoryName)' to '$NewDir' Size: $([System.Math]::Round(($($_.Length)/1KB),2))KB"  | Add-Content $LogfilePath
}
```

Note that, as in your own attempt, both solutions above rely on `$Source` and `$Destination` to contain *full* paths.